# Scale different width images to fit a row and maintain equal height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three images which are all **different widths**, but each the **same height**.

I want these images to be in a responsive row so that the combined width of these three images is 100% the width of the screen, all of the images have equal height, each image maintains its aspect ratio, and the images are not cropped.

One way to do it would be to set a different percentage width for each image in CSS, based upon each image's width according to the others. But I'm curious about a smarter way, probably using JavaScript/jQuery, which would be more efficient for doing this type of thing at a larger scale.

Comment: Maybe using them as background-images along with `background-size: cover`, also with `overflow: hidden` and fixed height.

Comment: I don't see a way this could be solved using pure css, since in css even if you could use CSS3's `calc()` you still would not be able to access the natural image dimensions, and thus, it's aspect ratio which I assume you will want to maintain (which will mean adjusting the row's height).

Comment: "and all of the images maintain the same height" this means that they must have their original, natural height or just that they are all equally high?

Comment: @connexo: I don't think the question makes any sense if you assume they must have their original height.

Comment: @DimasPante good idea, but I don't want to crop the images. I added that to the question now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This could work - by using css table layout.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kx8z85d2/)**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="//dummyimage.com/100x100/aaa" /></li>
  <li><img src="//dummyimage.com/200x100/bbb" /></li>
  <li><img src="//dummyimage.com/300x100/ccc" /></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

If the source images vary in height, you will have to use JavaScript.  Set all of the images to an arbitrary common height and find their combined width at that height.  Then increase the height by multiplying the difference of the target width and the combined width (as a percentage):

```js
$(window).on("load resize", function () { // wait for the images to complete loading
  $(".imgRow").each(function () {
    var row = $(this);
    var imgs = row.find("img");
    imgs.height(1000);
    var combinedWidth = imgs.get().reduce(function(sum, img) {
        return sum + img.clientWidth;
    }, 0);
    var diff = row.width() / combinedWidth;
    imgs.height(999 * diff); // 999 allows 1 px of wiggle room, in case it's too wide
  });
});
```

```css
.imgRow {
  clear: left;
}
.imgRow img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imgRow">
  <img src="//www.placecage.com/100/300" />
  <img src="//www.placecage.com/300/300" />
  <img src="//www.placecage.com/500/300" />
</div>
<div class="imgRow">
  <img src="//www.fillmurray.com/600/300" />
  <img src="//www.fillmurray.com/200/300" />
  <img src="//www.fillmurray.com/400/300" />
</div>
<div class="imgRow">
  <img src="//www.stevensegallery.com/500/300" />
  <img src="//www.stevensegallery.com/100/300" />
  <img src="//www.stevensegallery.com/300/300" />
</div>
<div class="imgRow">
  <img src="//www.placecage.com/400/300" />
  <img src="//www.placecage.com/600/300" />
  <img src="//www.placecage.com/250/300" />
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer for variable height images (which isn't necessarily what the OP wanted) - but the end result is solid.

Comment: What is the purpose of the .get() in the .get.reduce() here? I thought get was an ajax function?

Comment: @Marc, `imgs` is a jQuery object. jQuery's `get()` method returns the jQuery object's elements as an array. See http://api.jquery.com/get/#get2. This is a different method than the `$.get()` Ajax shorthand method. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get for comparison.

Comment: Thanks @gilly3 that's really helpful

Comment: Thanks, only one iteration required with this but I had to set size to 400, 399 and not 1000, 999 for it to work.  Haven't investigated the cause for 1000 to not work.

Answer (score 1):

My first approach to this would be to create three divs within a container div. Assign a height and a width of 33.33% to each of the three (and a float:left;) and 100% width to the container. Then set your three images to be the background of those three divs with the correct background properties such as

```
background-size:cover;
```

It might cut off bits of your images depending on the width of the screen but I don't think you will be able to get around that with images that are not the exact same size.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="image" style="background-image: url('/image.jpg');">
   </div>
   <div class="image" style="background-image: url('/image.jpg');">
   </div>
   <div class="image" style="background-image: url('/image.jpg');">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
   width:100%;
}
.image{
   float:left;
   width:33.33%;
   background-size:cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea, and similar to the comment @DimasPante posted above, but I don't want to crop the images.

Comment: If you don't want to crop the images your only other option may be to distort and stretch them if they have different widths as you say.

Answer (score 1):

The gist of the approach I'd take is to figure out how big your frame is, and figure out how wide the sum of your imgs are.  Then, using a ratio of those totals, resize each of the images.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var frameWidth = $("div.imgs").width()
var totalImgWidths = $("img#img1").width() + $("img#img2").width() + $("img#img3").width()
var ratio = frameWidth / totalImgWidths
var fudge = .95

$("img#img1").width(Math.floor($("img#img1").width() * ratio * fudge) )
$("img#img2").width(Math.floor($("img#img2").width() * ratio * fudge) )
$("img#img3").width(Math.floor($("img#img3").width() * ratio * fudge) )
})
```

See a quick [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/B8WpsGgsJvomrZwvJCFz) I quickly wrote up.  It's not fancy, and it's employing a bit of a fudge factor, so I'm happy if anyone can improve on it.

Comment: "Nailed it" with that hammer, did you? ;-)

Comment: @technophobia well yea, definitely hammered it in.  It's not good code.  I'm ashamed I didn't realize you could do this with css (see sdcr 's excellent answer)

Comment: I was just being silly; I saw your comment on sdcr's CSS voodoo answer!!! Just awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use this a basis for refining a solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/kb4gg35f/

For some reason this does not work as a snippet. It works as a fiddle, though.

```js
var images = $('img');
var accumulatedWidth = 0;
var widthResizeFactor;
var screenWidth = $('div').width();
var originalSizeArray = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var theImage = new Image();
    theImage.src = images[i].src;
    accumulatedWidth += theImage.width;
    originalSizeArray.push(theImage.width);
  }
  widthResizeFactor = screenWidth / accumulatedWidth;
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].width = originalSizeArray[i] * widthResizeFactor;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: left;
}
img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/200" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
</div>
```