# How do I maintain the aspect ratio of side-by-side images, keep the images the same height AND have fixed padding between images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I’m currently using the accepted table layout answer from this question: [Scale different width images to fit a row and maintain equal height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467025/scale-different-width-images-to-fit-a-row-and-maintain-equal-height) to place two images next to each other, maintain their aspect ratios, and keep them the same height when scaling. I would also like there to be a left padding of 8px on each image. I would like the padding to stay 8px no matter how wide the ul/table is.

Here is the jsfiddle I’m working on: https://jsfiddle.net/maryjames0/u1o5Lkmf/

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><img src="http://walops.com/wp-content/uploads/Puppy-Awesome-Wallpaper-100x100.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="http://photos.the-scientist.com/legacyArticleImages/2011/08/panda-200x100.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

So far, I’ve tried the following with no success:

- adding a padding-left of 8px to the images
- adding a padding-left of 8px to the list items
- adding a margin-left of 8px to the images
- adding a margin-left of 8px to the list items
- adding an 8px white left border to the images
- adding additional list items containing “placeholder” spans with width set to 8px

Ideally, I would like to solve this with CSS, but I am willing to accept javascript/jQuery solutions if that’s the only way to do it.

Thanks for any ideas and help!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to keep one dimension fixed (in this case height) while keeping the other at auto (in this case width). The browser will do everything for you. For the list items, either float or `display:inline-block` so they sit side-by side. https://jsfiddle.net/u1o5Lkmf/5/

You might need some JavaScript to find the smallest image and adjust the larger images to it instead of a hard-coded fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution. It may cut off a couple of pixels worth from the top of the image but I think it's unnoticeable enough to be okay.

See jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kfsfu9bx/

Add this:

```
li {
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -4px;
  width: calc(100% - 8px);
}
```